# como desenvolver un array de objetos multidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs

Teniendo en cuenta, que tengo el siguiente array de objetos multidimensional

```
const arr = [{ id:12, words:3, actions:[{uuid:1234, sequence:2, number:4}]}]
```

Como hago para volver plano el array y solo recuperar las propiedades, que estan dentro de actions uuid y number?

```
const service = disp.reduce((acc, el) =>({...acc, [el.id]: el.actions.reduce(
  (acc, e)=> ({...acc, [e.uuid]: e.numbers})
)}), {})
```

Pero me retorna un desorden intento solo objeter los atributos uuid y numbers de la propiedad actions

si me podrian ayudar por favor

a que el array, solo sea un objeto asi:

```
{uuid:32984, number:4}
```

Comment: Este no sería el caso en que necesite usar reduce() para algo así. Destructuring es suficiente:  ``const [actions] = arr[0].actions
console.log(actions)``

Answer (score 2):

Se puede usar `Object.assign` o `ES6 destructuring` para `object`:

```js
const arr = [{ id:12, words:3, actions:[{uuid:1234, sequence:2, number:4}]}];
//Object assign
let res = Object.assign({},{uuid:arr[0].actions[0].uuid, number:arr[0].actions[0].number});
console.log(res);
//ES6 Destructuring
let {uuid, number} = arr[0].actions[0];
let res2 = {uuid, number};
console.log(res2)
```

Enlaces:

[Object assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

[Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)